# Third party JavaScript not working in ruby on rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 4 in a Ruby on Rails app. I'm facing the problem is my 3rd party JavaScript files are not working in my app. The 3rd party JS file contains a carousel effect that is not working. My `application.js`contains

```
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require slick
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

[Deploy on Heroku](https://bit-app.herokuapp.com/), [Github Repository](https://github.com/asdimalix/bit.app).

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

According to the jquery-rails gem documentation, you also need to add

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

to your application.js file. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: This is directly from the jquery-rails documentation at rubygems.org:

```And if you want to use jQuery 3, you can require jquery3:

//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs```

[jquery-rails gem documentation](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your javascript code is being loaded as when I inspect the console on your Heroku app I see:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined
```

Looks like your `WOW` code exists in your `plugins.js` (also where your `Owl Carousel` source code lives).

In your `application.js` file add the `plugins.js` to ensure that it is loaded prior to the `active.js` file.

```
//= require plugins
//= require_tree .
```

(I would probably remove the `require_tree` and include each of your files separately dependent on what needs to be loaded in order).

Next, change your `Owl` js code similar to the snippet within the [Usage](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2#usage) section from the documentation. It should be something like this to ensure that it will load properly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".app_screenshots_slides").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    smartSpeed: 800,
    margin: 30,
    center: true,
    dots: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      480: {
        items: 3
      },
      992: {
        items: 5
      }
    }
  });
});
```

FWIW you have extra errors in the console as well (custom fonts not loaded and other jQuery errors). There also looks like some unused JS within your `active.js` file as well. This answer only includes what you have asked.

As an aside instead of having all the source js code in `plugins.js`, you can use Rails Assets to help you manage your dependencies better, here is the link for [OwlCarousel2](https://rails-assets.org/#/components/OwlCarousel2) if you are interested.